# I get a nullpointerexception when connecting to oracle DataBase

Tags: oracle, nullpointerexception, driver

Here is the stack trace:

```
 java.sql.SQLException
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:290)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:488)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
at com.boeing.DBReader.Server.makeConnection(Server.java:85)
at com.boeing.DBReader.Server.<init>(Server.java:26)
at com.boeing.DBReader.Reader.main(Reader.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:395)
at   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
... 11 more
Connection closed
```

And here is the code:

public class Server
{

```
private DataSource datasource;


public Server()
{
    try
    {
        createConnectionToDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e.toString());
    }
    makeConnection();
}

private void createConnectionToDatabase() throws Exception 
{
String connectionString = null;
String login = null;
String password = null;

System.out.println("In createConnectionToDatabase");

PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@***");

p.setUrl(connectionString);
p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
p.setUsername("**");
p.setPassword("**");

p.setJmxEnabled(true);
p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
p.setTestOnReturn(false);
p.setValidationInterval(30000);
p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
p.setMaxActive(100);
p.setInitialSize(10);
p.setMaxWait(10000);
p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(600);
p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
p.setMinIdle(10);
p.setLogAbandoned(true);
p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
        + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");

datasource = new DataSource();
datasource.setPoolProperties(p);


}

private void closeConnection(Connection con) {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            System.out.println("Could not close connection, WTF?");
        }
    }
}

private void makeConnection()
{
    Connection con = null;
    String queryString = "SQL QUERY GOES HERE ";
    try {
        System.out.println("Connection attempt");
        con = datasource.getConnection();

        System.out.println("Connection made no issues");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnection(con);
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
    }


}
```

I have the driver attached to the build path.. What am I doing wrong? This is set up without maven, and just a normal java project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure from the stack trace, but this looks wrong:

```
String connectionString = null;
String login = null;
String password = null;

System.out.println("In createConnectionToDatabase");

PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@***");

p.setUrl(connectionString);
```

You're setting the URL to `connectionString`, which is null.

Comment: Good catch!.. I have been staring for hours looking at everything else.. and that was it. Didn't even notice I left that in there. ThankS!